# Find function $f$ such that the performance of models $h_1$ and $h_2$ is similar

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, linear-model, expected-value

Suppose that $h_1$ and $h_2$ are the first and third order polynomials respectively, which are obtained by solving the OLS equation (using the training dataset). Also consider the following assumptions (the samples are IID):
$$\text{DGP (Data Generating Process)}:Y_i = f(X_i)+E_i , E_i \perp\!\!\!\perp X_i, \ \text{and} \\ E_i\perp\!\!\!\perp E_j , \mathbb{E}[E_i]=0$$
$$\text{Training dataset}:\mathcal{D}=\{(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)\} \\ \text{Test point}: (X_{n+1},Y_{n+1}) \\ \text{The outputs for} \ X_{n+1}:h_1(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}) \ \ \text{and} \ \ h_2(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}) \\ \text{Squared loss for model 1}: L_1(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1})=(Y_{n+1}-h_1(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}))^2 = (f(X_{n+1})+E_{n+1}-h_1(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}))^2 \\ \text{Squared loss for model 2}: L_2(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1})=(Y_{n+1}-h_2(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}))^2 = (f(X_{n+1})+E_{n+1}-h_2(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1}))^2$$ I want to find $f$ such that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with the property that $$\mathbb{P}(|\mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\mathbb{E}_{E_1,\dots,E_{n+1}}[L_1(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1})]] - \mathbb{E}_\mathcal{D}[\mathbb{E}_{E_1,\dots,E_{n+1}}[L_2(\mathcal{D},X_{n+1})]]|\lt \epsilon) \approx 1$$ In words, the performance of linear fit and cubic fit should be similar as the number of samples goes to infinity. I tried to apply the bias-variance decomposition but it didn't work because I don't know how to compute the bias and variance in this case. I guess that the constant function $f(x) = C$ works because the complexity of models is enough for fitting the constant function. Is this guess correct? Also is there any nontrivial $f$ which fulfils the condition?